# How do I get a list of connected TFS projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs-sdk, visual-studio-sdk

Using the Visual Studio 2010 and TFS 2010 SDK, I want to get the list of projects in the current collection that the user has selected.

How do I do this?

I can get the collection uri with this code, but not the projects:

```
TeamFoundationServerExt tfsExt =
               (TeamFoundationServerExt)Dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt");

if (tfsExt == null) return;

var activeTfsUri = tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext.DomainUri;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tpcURI);
    ICommonStructureService css = tpc.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
    ProjectInfo[] projects = css.ListProjects();
```

It should give you the name, uri and the status of the projects.

Comment: That looks like it will give me all projects though, am I correct? What I want is a list of projects in Visual Studio that the user is currently connected to (since you can choose to only show a smaller selected of projects that you have access to).

Comment: It returns all the projects that you have permission to see. But you're right, this is not how you get the list of projects currently connected to in Team Explorer. You would need to look at Visual Studio SDK (not TFS SDK) to figure that out.